# Big-$O$: prove $n^2\in O(n!)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help proving that $n^2\in O(n!)$ using the basic definition of Big-$O$.For example, show that there exists $a, B,b > 0$ such that $n^2 \leq B \cdot n!$ for all $n\geq b$.

Comment: Isn't $n!=n(n-1)(n-2)[(n-3)!]$?

Comment: Yes, I need help writing a formal proof

Comment: You can use induction to show that $n!\geq n^2$, and $n^2\geq n+1$, for $n\geq5$. Check that $5!\geq5^2$ and $5^2\geq 5+1$. Assume that $n^2\leq n!$ and $n^2\geq n+1$, then $(n+1)!\geq (n+1)n^2\geq (n+1)(n+1)=(n+1)^2$ and $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1\geq n+1+0+1=n+2$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, we can prove by induction on $k\ge0$ that $n^k\in o(n!)$. For the case $k=0$, this is the trivial condition $1\in o(n!)$. If it works when $k=j+1$, $n^j\sim(n-1)^j\in o((n-1)!)$. Multiplying by $n$, $n^{j+1}\in o(n!)$.

Comment: Thank you for to help me to edit the question.